# How do I set up VPN or Proxy for playing games through my home internet connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

In my University network, we have very restricted number of open ports. I would like to play my favourite games while in school, and I have fast connection at home. So VPN or Proxy comes to my mind, BUT:

1. I am not sure which of these would be best suited for me, VPN or Proxy, because VPN is primarily for emulating a local network, and Proxy very often needs an application to support it directly, which games don´t...
2. I need a good server/client free solution for this. Please, do you know any?

Answer (score 1):

Setup OpenVPN this way:

1. a server out of the firewalled network listening on port TCP 443
2. clients inside the firewalled network connecting to that server

The firewall of the network will see the SSL traffic on TCP 443 as it were HTTPS. Owned (I joke).

Not making promotion here, but to test if this technique works from your firewalled network, you can [download OpenVPN client](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) and try to connect to [SwissVPN](http://www.swissvpn.net/) service (test connection is free), which uses this very technique. If it works, you can setup a VPN server just like the swiss guys did for running their service.

Killer solution.